# How to recognize a non-minimum phase system from the Bode plot?

Tags: control-system, bode-plot

I have a bode diagram and I have to obtain if is it a non-minimum phase system or not.
I think we could obtain zeros and poles from the Bode diagram but I'm looking for a fast way to find the answer.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Non-minimum phase systems have one or more poles or zeros in the right half plane.

**A zero in the right half plane** has the same magnitude development as if it were in the LHP, but opposite phase development, i.e. the phase shift decreases with frequency.

**A pole in the right half plane** has the same magnitude development as if it were in the LHP, but opposite phase development, i.e. the phase shift increases with frequency.

So if you look at your Bode Plot of your transfer function and spot an increase in magnitude but a decrease in phase shift, then you know you have a zero in the RHP. A similar thing can be done to check if there is a pole in the RHP.

Comment: hi, thanks but this way is practical for simple systems.
consider a real physical system that has a complicated bode diagram and I wanna study that system. could we extend this way for that systems?

Comment: @MohammadHosini I'm not sure about that. I'm also not sure what a complicated Bode Plot is, or how you will draw a Bode Plot without knowing the transfer function a priori. The poles and zeros can be readily seen from the transfer function so why would you have to determine them by looking at a "complicated" Bode Plot?

Comment: in real life, we don't have a mathematical model of every system so we have to find it, there are many ways to do that and one of them is the bode diagram, you can approximate poles and zeros from the plot. 
but about how we draw a bode plot without having a transfer function, we can attach input to an oscillator then change the frequency and plot output proportional to the frequency, finally, we have the bode diagram.

Comment: But how can you distinguish the non-minimal system when you see Bode diagram? If you can attach an oscillator to input, you can also make a time plot?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a system with "minimum phase".

The two others are non-minimal phase systems (one with **delay**).

[image]

The non-minimal phase system can be recognized easily in the time domain...

One can see clearly that when the step goes "high",

... the output response first, **goes "low", then goes "high"**.

[image]

Here is a "good" application where "undershoot" can be corrected ...

https://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/CFKO200333239336383.pdf

NB : Can be this ... classified as "undershoot"?

[image]

Comment: The phenomenon that the step response decreases at the start, but then starts increasing to its steady state value is called **undershoot**. This is characteristic for systems with zeros in the right half plane.

Comment: Right. Seems to me it even shows up in-plane "controls", but hey, the systems are a way more complicated.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but I wanna examine the system from the bode diagram and time-domain analysis is not practical for me but your way is true.

Comment: How about the system with TF = (s-1)/(s+10)? It is a non-minimum phase system but the step response does not show the phenomenon of initially moving in the wrong direction as you said with step response.

Comment: It is not a "second-order" system, at least ...